# Cloning/Copying windows server r12

Tags: copy, clone, google-cloud-platform, windows-server-2012-r2

Is there a way to clone or copy a windows server r12 in google cloud?
I have looked for a way but I couldn't find a way to clone/copy the server into a new windows server r12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a Windows image using these instructions - it requires running `sysprep` and deleting the existing instance (but save the boot disk and then relaunch your initial instance). Then you can launch as many new copies as you need from the same image.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/creating-windows-os-image

You can also use persistent disk snapshots to backup and duplicate the disk data:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/creating-windows-persistent-disk-snapshot

Comment: So can I have two different servers with the same files inside?